# What precedes 'initwithidentifer'?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm just a bit lost to what the 'BlurryModalSegue' is referring to in this code.

```
- (void)presentSignupViewController {
// Storyboard ID
UIStoryboard *modalStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MyStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navController = [modalStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MySignupViewController"];
MySignupViewController *controller = [navController viewControllers][0];

// Configure your custom view controller, e.g. setting delegate
controller.delegate = self;

// Show VC
navController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;

BlurryModalSegue *segue = [[BlurryModalSegue alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"SignupScene" source:self destination:navController];

[segue perform];
}
```

It is not mine and I am just seeing if it will work for me, but the poster doesn't include the .h file. Is it the name of the viewController? If anyone could point me in the right direction to what this would be, that would be great.

Link: https://coderwall.com/p/-yka_q

Comment: On the page that you are referring to is a link to a Github project containing BlurryModalSegue.h, BlurryModalSegue.m, a sample project and a ReadMe ... . It looks like a custom "storyboard segue" which is documented here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomSegues/CreatingCustomSegues.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used the BlurryModelSegue pod, and if you import that pod into an XCode project you will be able to view the BlurryModalSegue.hm files. This is simply a custom segue that is used to pop a view controller with a blurred UIImage as its background.